# Failed to process checkbox values with AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form with text, radio and checkbox inputs. When I submit it with AJAX, I only get the last checkbox value in array.

My HTML file:

```
<form class="ajaxonsubmit" action="process.php" method="post">

<label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name">
<label>Father's Name</label><input type="text" name="father_name">

<label>Gender</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="gender">Male <br>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="gender">Female <br>

<label>Options</label>
<select name="campus">
    <option value="1">Option1 </option>
    <option value="2">Option2 </option>
</select>

<label>Check List</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3">

<button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

My JS file.

```
$('.ajaxonsubmit').on('submit', function() {
var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#wrap").html(data);
    }
});

return false;
```

});

I am using var_dump($_POST); function in process.php to check the array and I get ["check"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: adding check[] simply doesnot store your checkboxes value in array. You need to make array using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form data , and access in PHP side

```
$('.ajaxonsubmit').on('submit', function(e) {

e.preventdefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        $("#wrap").html(data);
    }
  });


});
```

in PHP

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Good answer, one minor thing, but e.preventdefault() will not be recognized, e.preventDefault() with a capital D will.

Answer (score 1):

Add class="checkBoxClass" to your checkbox,

Then in your js, just add the following code to add the data into your chkArray

```
var chkArray = [];
        $(".checkBoxClass:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Finally append the array to the data you are posting

Cheers.

Comment: Which is the right place of this js code in my script?